# How do I use caching in an MVC 5 web application?

Tags: c#, .net, caching

```
Line 56:<cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)">

Line 57:Current Time Inside Cache Tag Helper: @DateTime.Now

Line 58:</cache>
```

//I am getting this error message

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Parser Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Expected "}".

Comment: So,what all properties you have used in your OutputCache attribute? Would be helpful if you could share the code too

Comment: I was able to resolve the error. I found a useful website about caching asp.net mvc , this is the website that I used : http://techfunda.com/howto/276/store-data-into-cache-in-asp-net-mvc. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error. I found a really useful website about caching asp.net mvc, this is the website that I used: techfunda.com/howto/276/store-data-into-cache-in-asp-net-mvc. It contains information about different types of caches and explains more what each cache type does.

//Code added in the action result methods in my controller for the views I want to be cached

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache", Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
```

//Code added in the web config

```
<caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="Cache" duration="30" varyByParam="none"/>
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

For more information about caching, please visit the following website : techfunda.com/howto/276/store-data-into-cache-in-asp-net-mvc.